# Using Javascript to ONLY hide a link/txt/div

Tags: javascript

I have a site with a Javascript image viewer to enlarge my pics.

Therefore if you browse with JS enabled you dont have to see the link
to another page witch shows the pics enlarged.

if JS is disabled you wont see my function to enlarge pics with javascript, but
will see my link to the enlarged page.

I need a code to just hide the link. i keep finding TOGGLE switches.

Comment: It should not be so difficult to extract the hiding part from the toggle functions you've found.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hiding the link, just put it in `noscript` tags:

```
<noscript>
  <a href="/url">This link only shows up for those without javascript enabled</a>
</noscript>
```

Comment: i don't think its a good idea. Imagine you have a lot of those elements. Personally i would not like to have those noscript tags everywhere in my HTML structure.

Comment: True. If I had a site that had many elements like this, I would probably go with pleasedontbelong's answer. This here is probably what I would use in the case that I actually _needed_ the element to be hidden when javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

usually what you need to do is to put your image inside a link that has both `href` and `onclick` attributes

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/link_to_my_big_image.jpg" onclick="showBigImage();return false;">
    <img src="my_small_image.jpg" alt="click me"/>
</a>
```

if JS is disabled, the onclick wont work, and if js is enabled the link wont redirect the page

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

what i do in those cases is setting a class named nojs on the body or the HTML. Then i remove it with javascript. Then you can use the following CSS to cover both cases:

```
.js .yourelement {
   display: none;
}

.nojs .yourelement {
   display: block;
}
```

With jQuery you can do:

```
$(function(){ $("body").addClass("js").removeClass("nojs"); });
```

Its how its done in the [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) as well.